# MongoDB update an object inside in an array inside an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update the quantity on a field from an object in an array nested in an array. And I can't figure the query to do it.

I can update a field in an object inside one array. But when I try to go one level down I get a "too many $ in the query"

this is the document. how to increase the quantity of the red wine item from 3 to 5? for example

```
{
    "_id" : "bTTALd6kuBfEqFEiW",
    "charges" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "0",
            "type" : "charge",
            "selected" : "tab-unselected",
            "concept" : "booking",
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "rGmt5wLuLN6MyW3og",
                    "item" : "red Wine",
                    "quantity" : 3,
                    "price" : 280
                },
{
                    "_id" : "rGmt5gwLuLN6MyW3o",
                    "item" : "white Wine",
                    "quantity" : 3,
                    "price" : 280
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`documentation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) about the positional operator `$[]` and `arrayFilters`.

```
const query = {
  _id: "bTTALd6kuBfEqFEiW"
};

const update = {
  $set: { "charges.$[charge].items.$[item].quantity": 5 }
};

const options = {
  arrayFilters: [ { "charge._id": "0" }, { "item._id": "rGmt5wLuLN6MyW3og" } ]
};

db.test.update(query, update, options);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I will study the docs. I have changed the update  from $set to $inc to add 2 to the current quantity. Thanks.